# Probability of a certain subsequence from a sequence of i.i.d. uniformly distributed discrete random variables.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Let $\{x_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $x_k\sim U_{[[ 1,n]]}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ where $U_{[[1,n]]}$ is the uniform distribution on the discrete set $[[1,n]]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Fix $a\in[[1,n]]$. What is the probability that there is a subsequence $\{x_{k_j}\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\forall j\in\mathbb{N}$, $x_{k_j} = a\in[[1,n]]$? I think it should be $1$ but I don't know how to show it. References to learn about problems like this are also appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking for the probability that an infinite number of variables in the i.i.d. sequence take the value $a$?

Comment: @Michael yes exactly.

Comment: Define Bernoulli indicator variables $Y_k$ to be 1 if $X_k=a$ , and 0 else. Then use, for example, the law of large numbers, or the Borel-Cantelli Lemma.

Comment: This sounds fruitful I will explore that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to deal with such questions on a formal level, we need the concepts of "infinite product of sigma algebras", "infinite product of probability measures", and "infinite product of probability spaces". You can read up on this, for example, here: https://jpmccarthymaths.com/2012/01/08/infinite-products-of-probability-spaces/

Assuming all of these concepts, we can proceed as follows.

First, we have

Probability($a$ occurs infinitely often) = $1 -$ Probability($a$ occurs only finitely many times).$\quad\quad$(i)

Moreover

Probability($a$ occurs only finitely many times) = $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty$ Probability($a$ occurs exactly $k$ times),$\quad\quad$(ii)

since the events {$a$ occurs exactly $k$ times } for differente values of $k$ are disjoint.

Let's calculate Probability($a$ occurs exactly $0$ times).

We have

{$a$ occurs exactly $0$ times }$ = \cap_{j=1}^{\infty} ${$a$ does not occur the first $j$ times }.$\quad\quad$(iii)

Also,

{$a$ does not occur the first $j_1$ times } $\supseteq$ {$a$ does not occur the first $j_2$ times }

for $j_1 \leq j_2$.

In other words, the sequence of events on the r.h.s of (iii) is monotonically descending.

From this, we get, using a "well known" property of probability measures (continuity from above, see, for example, here: [Properties of Probability Measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16004/properties-of-probability-measure)),

Probability($a$ occurs exactly $0$ times ) = $\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}$ Probability($a$ does not occur the first $j$ times ).$\quad\quad$(iv)

Now,

Probability($a$ does not occur the first $j$ times )$ = (\frac{n-1}n)^j$,$\quad\quad$(v)

since the first $j$ terms in the sequence $(x_k)$ are not allowed to be equal to $a$, while the remaining terms can take on any value.

Combining (iv) and (v), we find

Probability($a$ occurs exactly $0$ times ) = $0$.

Next, let's calculate Probability($a$ occurs exactly $2$ times).

We have

{$a$ occurs exactly $2$ times }$ = \cup_{1 \leq j_1 < j_2 < \infty} ${$a$ occurs exactly at positions $j_1$ and $j_2$ },$\quad\quad$(vi)

where the union on the r.h.s is disjoint.

From this, we get

Probability($a$ occurs exactly $2$ times $) = \sum_{1 \leq j_1 < j_2 < \infty} $Probability($a$ occurs exactly at positions $j_1$ and $j_2$ ).$\quad\quad$(vii)

Moreover, for fixed $1 \leq j_1 \leq j_2 < \infty$, we have

{$a$ occurs exactly at positions $j_1$ and $j_2$ } = $\cap_{k = j_2}^\infty$ {$a$ occurs at positions $j_1$ and $j_2$, and maybe at positions after $k$, but not elsewhere},$\quad\quad$(viii)

where the sequence of events on the r.h.s. is monotonically descending for $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Using this, we get as above,

Probability($a$ occurs exactly at positions $j_1$ and $j_2$) $= \lim_{k \geq j_2, k \rightarrow\infty}$ Probability($a$ occurs at positions $j_1$ and $j_2$, and maybe at positions after $k$, but not elsewhere),$\quad\quad$(ix)

and for $k \geq j_2$

Probability($a$ occurs at positions $j_1$ and $j_2$, and maybe at positions after $k$, but not elsewhere) = $(\frac1n)^2(\frac{n-1}n)^{k-2}$.$\quad\quad$(x)

Combining (ix) and (x), we get

Probability($a$ occurs exactly at positions $j_1$ and $j_2$) $=$0$.\quad\quad$(xi)

Now, combining (vii) and (xi), we get

Probability($a$ occurs exactly $2$ times $) = $0$.\quad\quad$(xii)

The cases $k = 1$ and $k \geq 3$ are embarassingly similar to the case $k = 2$.

We find for all $k \in \{0, 1, \ldots \}$

Probability($a$ occurs exactly $k$ times ) = $0$.$\quad\quad$(xiii)

Combining (ii) and (xiii) gives

Probability($a$ occurs only finitely many times) = $0$.$\quad\quad$(xiv)

Combining (i) and (xiv) now gives

Probability($a$ occurs infinitely often) = $1$,

as conjectured.

So we see that once we have the aforementioned concepts of infinite products of sigma algebras etc, the calculations boil down to basic calculus.

If you're not familiar with those infinite products of sigma algebras etc, you should study them. You've seen that they're useful.

Comment: Wow! This is a really great answer. Thanks for writing this.